# How to get a random button in Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I have 4 buttons in my layout, how can I pick a random one?
I was thinking of creating an array, but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure exactly what you're asking, so I'll suggest a couple potential solutions

---

Create an array of references to your buttons, hide them and pick one at random to show.
Like this:

```
buttons[0].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
buttons[1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

---

You could also have only one button and just change its properties such as text and what it does when you click it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it did the job. Sorry for bad question description, pretty noob in programming. Only now I have realised that Button is a class and I have successfully created and array of Buttons.